# highchart 3d column - show "beta axis title" and "beta axis label"

Tags: javascript, highcharts

English is not my native language.If you don't understand my question,please tell me.

I want to show the "beta axis title" and "beta axis label" in highchart. What I want is as follows:

[image: I want]

However, what I got is here:

[image: I got]

I googled.I didn't find any solution to my problem.

my javascript code is as follows.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        margin: 75,
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 15,
            beta: 50,
            depth: 110
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    xAxis:{
    title: {
          text: "构建日期"
      },
        categories: ["2010-10-17","2010-10-18","2010-10-19","2010-10-20","2010-10-21","2010-10-22"],

    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
          text: "内存(MB)"
      }
         },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            depth: 40,
            stacking: true,
            grouping: false,
            groupZPadding: 10
        }
    },
    series: [{
            name: 'HUAWEI',
        data: [1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        stack: 0
    }, {
            name: 'XIAOMI',
        data: [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2],
        stack: 1
    }, {
            name: 'oppo',
        data: [7, 9, 8, 7, 5, 8],
        stack: 2
    }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `zAxis` categories to have the `labels`, and the `zAxis` `title` to have the title. It is *important to note that to show the labels, you **need** to define a min and max*. This is a minimal example that will show it all (on top of eachother):

```
zAxis: {
  title: {
    text: 'TITLE HERE',
    },
  min: 0,
  max: 2,
  categories: ["HUAWEI", "XIAOMI", "oppo"] 
}
```

[image: Ex1]

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/0uc1g8b5/3/

There is a lot of options for tweaking the look of this, you should have a look at the API on `zAxis` `labels`/`titles`.

**API on zAxis.titles:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/zAxis.title

For example you can rotate and have it look like this:

[image: ex2]

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/0uc1g8b5/5/

Or you can use skew3d and have it look like this:

[image: ex3]

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/0uc1g8b5/6/

It depends a lot on what you want to write as the title and labels. You will just have to experiment.

Comment: If this answers your question it would be nice if you would accept it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry.It is my first time to ask a question in the stackoverflow. I have accept your answer.Thanks again.